# NextAuth - Type error: Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'Session'

Tags: typescript, github, deployment, build, next-auth

I am trying to deploy my application.
When I try to build on my local machine it works fine, but when the build runs on GitHub it is not working.

For information, I am using yarn and yarn build to build the project.

According to most of my research, it should not be an issue. Maybe it comes from typescript, or I made a mistake I do not see, or it could be a wrong configuration of the GitHub CI? I do not know...

my code for
*[...nextauth].ts*

```js
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"

const GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL =
  "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?" +
  new URLSearchParams({
    prompt: "consent",
    access_type: "offline",
    response_type: "code",
  })

/**
 * Takes a token, and returns a new token with updated
 * `accessToken` and `accessTokenExpires`. If an error occurs,
 * returns the old token and an error property
 */
async function refreshAccessToken(token: any) {
  try {
    const url =
      "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?" +
      new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!.toString(),
        client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!.toString(),
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: token.refreshToken,
      })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      method: "POST",
    })

    const refreshedTokens = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw refreshedTokens
    }

    return {
      ...token,
      accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + refreshedTokens.expires_at * 1000,
      refreshToken: refreshedTokens.refresh_token ?? token.refreshToken, // Fall back to old refresh token
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Oups", error)

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    }
  }
}

// For more information on each option (and a full list of options) go to
// https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorization: GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
    }),
  ],

  theme: {
    colorScheme: "auto", // "auto" | "dark" | "light"
    brandColor: "#004821", // Hex color code
    logo: "XXX", // Absolute URL to image
  },

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      // Initial sign in
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          accessToken: account.access_token,
          accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account!.expires_at! * 1000,
          refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
          user,
        }
      }

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires!) {
        return token
      }

      // Access token has expired, try to update it
      return refreshAccessToken(token)
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token.user!,
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      session.error = token.error

      return session
    },
  },

}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

And the error I have is the following:

```bash
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts:99:15
Type error: Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'Session'.

   97 |     async session({ session, token }) {
   98 |       session.user = token.user!,
>  99 |       session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      |               ^
  100 |       session.error = token.error
  101 | 
  102 |       return session
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

EDIT:
So with the different comments I got, I think that the issue was due to an issue with the next auth version.

Comment: The versions of what Github CI and your local machine might not match, this change happened semi recently: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/4953/files#diff-4a09ba4be6baf319f19fb95085e3c72cb52ab694f013b67ddb8861042a0f9b69

Comment: I recommend cleaning out your node_modules in case your version is behind what CI is using

Comment: So, my node_modules is not push on GitHub. I tried to *rm -rf node_modules*, and I used *yarn* to download them again. It still builds on my local machine. I tried to change the node version in the CI for the exact same one as on my machine and I still have the same issue.

Note: It is my first time using the GitHub CI

Comment: So, I have changed the version of nextauth for 4.12.0, and I do not have this issue.

Answer (score 14):

First, you need to add a folder called `types` in the root of your project and then add a file called `next-auth.d.ts` with the following content:

```js
// my-project/types/next-auth.d.ts

import NextAuth from 'next-auth'

declare module 'next-auth' {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    accessToken?: string
  }
}
```

Now when you can do the following without getting an error:

```
// my-project/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  // ...
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.id_token = account.id_token
        token.provider = account.provider
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken as string
      return session
    },
  }
  // ...
}
```

Note: you can also declare the module inside the `[...nextauth].ts` file.

Note 2: You may need to declare additional properties for the JWT interface:

```js
// my-project/types/next-auth.d.ts

declare module 'next-auth/jwt' {
  interface JWT {
    id_token?: string
    provider?: string
    accessToken?: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm still having an issue though. It seems my `jwt` callback is not getting called, and my `Session` object when I debug has only `expired` property, so my added `accessToken` does not seem to be applied. Do you know what could be a reason?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently (today), and came up with the following solution for my build, by extending the DefaultSession type from next-auth:

```js
interface SessionExtension extends DefaultSession {
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
}
```

Not sure if it will help your specific case, but hope it helps!

Edit: To elaborate and clarify

where I was seeing the error was in my `apollo.ts` file (I am using [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) and graphql fed through a Rails backend). In [this PR](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/pull/4953/files#diff-4a09ba4be6baf319f19fb95085e3c72cb52ab694f013b67ddb8861042a0f9b69) from October 9th, 2022, there are some changes made to the `Default Session` interface (`packages/next-auth/src/core/types.ts:423`) from `export interface DefaultSession extends Record<string, unknown> {...` to `export interface DefaultSession {...`. By removing the extension from `Record<string, unknown>` in the [DefaultSession interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces), it no longer allowed the `DefaultSession` to be extended in the way [records allow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), which means that the type definition that was given by the nextauth team could not be altered by us. So by changing our code to be

```js
import { type DefaultSession } from 'next-auth';

...

interface SessionExtension extends DefaultSession {
  accessToken: string;
  apiToken: string;
  refreshToken: string;
}

...


const session = (await getSession()) as SessionExtension;

...
```

I manually changed the properties that the `Default Session` could allow, to let us access those other fields that we needed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your solution? Its quite hard for new Next/NextAuth folks like me to understand this. If possible, please add some reference documentations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the problem in the jwt callback. Try to change the order of the props to:

```
async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
  // Initial sign in
  if (account && user) {
    return {
      accessToken: account.access_token,
      accessTokenExpires: Date.now() + account!.expires_at! * 1000,
      refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
      user,
    }
  }

  // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
  if (Date.now() < token.accessTokenExpires!) {
    return token
  }

  // Access token has expired, try to update it
  return refreshAccessToken(token)
}
```